# Stop raising Click Event in a specific area of a UserControl

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, graphics

**Problem**

A UserControl raises by default the `Click` Event when a mouse button is pressed. Is there a way to prevent the event from raising when clicking on a specific area of the UserControl?

**Code**

Suppose that we have this specific UserControl. There is a red rectangle: I want to raise the click event only in the white area.
I've tried to override the OnMouseClick sub:

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Dim noClickArea As New Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50)

    'Draw the red rectangle
    Private Sub UserControl1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        Using gr As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
            gr.Clear(Color.White)
            gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, noClickArea)
        End Using
    End Sub

    'This aims to prevent the mouseClick event on noClickArea
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseClick(e As MouseEventArgs)
        If Not noClickArea.Contains(e.Location) Then
            MyBase.OnMouseClick(e)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is a test Form that use this UserControl and show a message box on click:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub UserControl11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UserControl11.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Click")
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Result**

Overriding *OnMouseClick* don't produce the expected result:

[image: Output]

How can I achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding `OnMouseClick`, but you have subscribed to the `Click` event in your Form.
`OnMouseClick` is called after `OnClick`, so you suppress `MouseClick`, but the `Click` event has already been raised.
Override `OnClick` instead. Or subscribe to the `MouseClick` event in your Form.

Note that `EventArgs` of the `OnClick` method is actually a `MouseEventArgs` object, so you can cast `EventArgs` to `MouseEventArgs`:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(e As EventArgs)
    If noClickArea.Contains(CType(e, MouseEventArgs).Location) Then Return
    MyBase.OnClick(e)
End Sub
```

Then, override `OnPaint` instead of subscribing to the `Paint` event in your UserControl.
Also, do not use `Me.CreateGraphics` in that event or method override, it doesn't make sense.
Use the Graphics object provided by the `PaintVentArgs`:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, noClickArea)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub
```

As a suggestion (since I don't know what is the real use case), if you want to fill the whole Control's background with a color, set the Background Color of the Control in the Designer instead of using **`Graphics.Clear()`** in that context.